# index of jsf component that fired event

Tags: jsf

This has to be a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the right keywords to google on: I have an action listener that can receive an event from any one of multiple checkboxes that were all generated from the same line of jsp in a dataTable. How can I tell from the action listener which one issued the event?

In particular, I need the index of the component so I can map it to an ordered list in the model. I know I can get the UIComponent object, and from there I can get the client ID of the component.  And knowing that the client ID has the component's index embedded in it, yes I *could* do the sleazy thing, and parse the index from the client ID. But I know that would be a horrible, fragile and unmaintainable hack.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I should have added: I want the index so that I can implement mutex behavior on the list of checkboxes (I know, radio buttons are technically the right thing for this, but the components are in different sections of the screen, so radio buttons would look isolated and out of context.) I also know I can accomplish the mutex behavior with javascript, but I think it's messier to add a javascript function for that. Suggestions for elegant client side solutions would also be great.

Comment: The functional requirement is unclear, so the most elegant solution cannot be given. What's the purpose of those checkboxes? Is it one per row? Is the purpose to select multiple rows? Are there multiple per row? What index exactly are you talking about? The row index? Or the checkbox's index? Why exactly do you need the index? Etc.

Comment: It's one checkbox per row, single-select (i.e. mutually exclusive). There are actually two interleaved mutual exclusion groups, and a particular row might belong to one group or the other. So really, you end up being able to check a total of two items, one from each group. The idea of the index is to identify which one was actually selected, so the others can be de-selected. I hope that adds more clarity than confusion :)

Comment: @nclark: the answer of shredder contains nonsensicial code which won't work at all (the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` doesn't support an `actionListener` at all). If you actually ended up with a workable solution, you should post that as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DataTables `var` attribute, you should be able to do this

```
<h:dataTable ...  var="currentRow">
  ....
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox ... actionListener="#{blah.doThis}">
      <f:attribute name="curRec" value="#{currentRow}" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

bean:

```
public void doThis(ActionEvent ae)
{
    TreeMap myMap = (TreeMap)ae.getComponent().getAttributes().get("curRec");
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** The binding variable of your datatable should have the method `getRowIndex();`. That should give you the index of the record that caused the event in the table. I'm referencing an ICEfaces project, so I apologize if that isn't correct. Let me know, thx.

Answer (score 1):

After an initial search, I think this could help you.

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html

Have you tried to use f:param in addition to the checkbox values to pass custom parameters, so that would be more cleaner than working with ID's to manipulate business logic. ID.